# Play audio stream on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, stream, webradio

I'm developing a webradio player application on Android (API 17) and I'd like to play an audio flux from the Internet with the MediaPlayer Android library. This is my code:

```
String url = "http://stream.url.net/" ;
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

And within an `OnPreparedListener()` I launch the audio: `mediaPlayer.start();`

All goes well with this code on my old Android device (API 10).

However, when I launch it on my new Android device (API 17), the application is stuck on the `prepareAsync()` and the player never appears. How can I fix this?

Comment: i know that you want to do it on a different thread, but does .prepare() work?

Comment: Nope it doesn't work, I've the same problem

Comment: Can you post all the code?  whats 'mp'?  everywhere else you have included, you reference 'mediaPlayer'

Comment: also, obviously: http://stream.url.net/ is not an audio file

Comment: Hum sorry... It's mediaPlayer.start(); 
Obviously, I'm not using this url ;)

Comment: I believe the code is the source of the problem. Do you still want me to post the all thing?

Comment: Nobody can help me ? :)